# Oracle JDBC Resultset.getString("COLUMN_DEF") returns lower case quoted string

Tags: oracle, jdbc

With oracle JDBC driver (ojdbc7.jar), when I do x=Resultset.getString("COLUMN_DEF") for a column where the default value is 'N/A' in the database ('N/A' set at table creation, 'N/A' seen with DBeaver tool) the JDBC driver return x="'n/a'" (with postgres and mysql it returns x="N/A").

do you have an idea of why it is in lower case et why it is quoted inside the  result string?

thanks in advance for any kind of help on this issue!

PS: how I use the database metadata object:

```
private static void readColumnMetaData(AMIDBLoader dbLoader, DatabaseMetaData metaData, String internalCatalog, String externalCatalog, String _table, Map<String, String> amiEntityMap, Map<String, String> amiFieldMap) throws SQLException
    {
        try(ResultSet resultSet = metaData.getColumns(internalCatalog, internalCatalog, _table, "%"))
        {
            while(resultSet.next())
            {
                String table = resultSet.getString("TABLE_NAME");
                String name = resultSet.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
                String type = resultSet.getString("TYPE_NAME");
                int size = resultSet.getInt("COLUMN_SIZE");
                int digits = resultSet.getInt("DECIMAL_DIGITS");
                String def = resultSet.getString("COLUMN_DEF");
```

code for the table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE "router_locations" ( 
"id" NUMBER(*, 0),
"continentCode" VARCHAR2(3) DEFAULT 'N/A',
"countryCode" VARCHAR2(3) DEFAULT 'N/A' 
);;
```

Jerome

Comment: Forgot about DBeaver mention please, my problem is that the JDBC driver return "'n/a'" when the table is cretated with                                                CREATE TABLE "router_locations" (
  "id" NUMBER(*, 0),
  "continentCode" VARCHAR2(3) DEFAULT 'N/A',
  "countryCode" VARCHAR2(3) DEFAULT 'N/A'
);;

Comment: Completely irrelevant, but [Oracle does not recommend using quoted identifiers for database object names.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html). They are a pain to work with, so if you're setting up something new you might want to reconsider those table and column names...

Comment: The problem I have is not with identifiers but with the default value for the field, I have updated my question with my code.

Comment: Which version of Oracle and JDBC driver (full version numbers please; ojdbc7 just means it is for Java 7, it is not a version number)

Comment: ojdbc8 12.2.0.1.0

Answer (score 1):

We managed to find where the string was modified and the JDBC driver is ok .. thanks for your help.